# URL Rewrite 1.1 within VisualStudio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, url-rewriting

I have changed one of my apps to use URL Rewrite 1.1 in IIS7.5 which works great (as some of you my have seen from previous posts) but I have an issue that this doesnt work when developing as Visual Studio Webserver doesnt seem to support it.

Is there a way to get it work so we can actually debug it, rather than writing a completely different url mapping section for when we are developing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow great timing for the question.  I just happened across it while browsing today.  But I just released support for URL Rewrite syntax in my URL Rewriter 3.5 yesterday.

http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=36792

URL Rewriter 3.5 is able to run in the Visual Studio Webserver.  It supports Apache mod_rewrite and MS URL Rewrite config.  The MS URL Rewrite is still in it's preliminary stages, but I would be happy to work with you to get this working.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for the link, I have downloaded your project and will give it a go today when I get chance. Do you have an email address that I can contact you on to discuss this further?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this, is set it up on your local IIS to run the site (Pointing the home-directory at the source files)

Then use the menu "Debug" > "Attach to Process" option.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx

Off the top of my head: the process is "w3wp.exe" in iis7

This will then allow you to debug the app via IIS (Which has the URL Re-Writing support)

Comment: Yeah I thought this might be the problem, debugging is just a pain in the ass doing it with real IIS.

Just hoping there was some setting or something, might have to write a different mapping agent dependant on where it is run, which is REALLY bad as not testing the correct code paths when debugging

Comment: running it from iis and attaching the process should be exactly the same as running it via VS IDE.